# flex 4 states and using includein with actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

How do you handle states and the "includeIn" tag in ActionScript?  For example:

```
var newState:State = new State();
var comp:Group = new Group();
comp.includeIn = newState;
```

This is not valid code, but it's what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 1):

From Adobe Help: **About Spark skins**

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSC8DB0C28-F7A6-48ff-9899-7957415A0A49.html

Quote:

> The excludeFrom and includeIn properties can be set only in MXML.
>   You cannot set the values of these properties in ActionScript.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't investigated this yet but I guess includeIn/excludeFrom metadata is translated into set of AddChild/RemoveChild State overrides. What you want might look like the following:

```
var newState:State = new State();
var comp:Group = new Group();
newState.overrides = [new AddChild(this, comp)];
```